# Connections mirroring in Django tests

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

I have a multi-database configuration of Django 1.10 and json fixtures for connections. For example my configuration looks like

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'default',
        ...,
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_default',
        }
    },
    'second': {
        'NAME': 'second',
        ...,
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_second',
            'MIRROR': 'default',
        }
    }
}
```

When Django bootstrap testing environment it loads `TestCase.fixtures` into not-mirrored connections (in my case only into `test_default`).
When test case next tries to get model placed in `second` connection it fails with DoesNotExists.

This happens because fixtures are loaded into first connection that is not committed because of using savepoints between running test cases.

Consequently all tests that assume presence of data in mirroring connections like in master connection will fail!

This looks like a problem with Django test bootstrap algorithm.
Also possible that i do something completely wrong.

Why Django not loads fixtures also into mirrored connections?

-- OR --

Why Django not starts transactions *after* loading fixtures?